# Repairing or installing Port Audio on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: sound

I use Musescore on Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1 to write music. Part of the time I use a Korg Microkey2-61 midi keyboard. I have two computers with the same OS. On one, I have the input working fine. I just tried to switch to the other (faster) computer, but when I try to set Port Audio as the input, Musescore crashes. I reinstalled Musescore — no change.

I think perhaps Port Audio is either not installed or not working but can't figure out how to check that and repair or replace Port Audio, if necessary. The only instructions I find for Port Audio call for a whole series of steps, including compiling and building and other procedures I've never done and don't have the background for. Should I just do a clean install of Ubuntu Mate. (Or should I switch to a different Ubuntu?)

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is EOL, so you have to upgrade it to 20.04 LTS. Also it may be hardware issue.

Comment: I checked. I'm running 20.04.1 and I don't think it's a hardware problem since I'm able to play the keyboard using LMMS.